# Getting "can't create Thread: Resource temporarily unavailable" since I started using Capybara::Poltergeist

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, multithreading, capybara, poltergeist

I recently added some code that uses Capybara::Poltergeist to fetch information from pages that work with JavaScript.
(I'll be happy to replace it with a something else if there is an option)

The I load the page , input some data into it , click a button , wait for return value.

In order to try and have as little memory leaks , zombie processes etc. I use the following:

```
Capybara.default_driver         = :poltergeist
Capybara.default_max_wait_time  = 60
Capybara.javascript_driver      = :poltergeist

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {js_errors: false} )
end

capybara_session                = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist , timeout: 60 )
```

I do some actions .....

```
capybara_session.try(:reset_session!)
capybara_session.try(:driver).try(:quit)
Capybara.try(:drivers).try(:clear)
```

But I'm still getting ***"can't create Thread: Resource temporarily unavailable"*** after a few hours of operation.

Any idea how to solve or replace this?

Comment: Have you tried the master branch of poltergeist?  There was a change made on October 18th dealing with a leak that isn't in a release version yet which might affect this -

Comment: I'll give it a try, although this sounds a little more serious. It a full thread that isn't closed, not just a memory leak. Btw, my combo of every quit/clear/reset command I found is ok? I thought of adding ps/kill system commands for extra safety. Thank you for commenting.

Comment: The reset_session! and quit calls look reasonable - not sure why you need to clear drivers though, since all that contains is the registered driver blocks.  Looking at your code again I also notice that you're passing a second parameter to Session.new -- the second parameter is the app under test (not needed by your use case).  This could be the root cause of your issue since it would create a thread in which to run the app (unless you have Capybara.run_server = false).  It should just be Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)

Comment: 1) Regarding the extra clear/quit , I checked with 'ps -ef | grep phantom' , only after the quit the process disappears. 2) Regarding the app , I took an example how to initiate js_errors: false , I moved it into the Session.new and it did the same , so I removed this code now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes the quit is required -- it's the `Capybara.try(:drivers).try(:clear)` which probably isn't doing anything for you

Comment: You're probably right , but after seeing so many discussions about memory leaks and the issue I had with it. Why not add another clear into the mix? (BTW I have multiple workers running this over and over , so clearing anything I can makes me sleep better at night :) )

Comment: Because if you register the driver with the same name next time it's overwriting it anyway - or if you're not customizing the driver config for each session then just call register_driver once and leave it alone.  All drivers contains is the blocks you register when you call `register_driver`, which then get called based on the name you pass in Session.new

Comment: Now I had to remove Capybara.try(:drivers).try(:clear) , since once I removed the Capybara.register_driver block , on the second time Capybara was called it failed with: "no driver called :poltergeist was found, available driver".

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was saying - you only need to register once and then no need to clear it

Comment: BTW , if you'll put it in an answer I'll gladly mark it as the right one. And add a summary of settings (the ones above and a few more I found) for proper Capybara::Poltergeist usage.

Comment: Addded as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue here is the incorrect use of Session.new.  The second parameter to Session.new is supposed to be the app being tested, and if passed in triggers the creation of a server thread for that app. Since you're not actually testing an app that parameter should be nil (which it defaults to) so

```
capybara_session = Session.new(:poltergeist)
```

The `timeout: 60` option gets passed to the driver when creating it.

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, js_errors: false, timeout: 60 )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a recap of the options I'm using now.
Seems like a good combo for performance and no loose threads.

```
timeout                                               = 45
Capybara.run_server                                   = false
Capybara.default_max_wait_time                        = timeout
Capybara.default_driver                               = :poltergeist
Capybara.javascript_driver                            = :poltergeist
capybara_session                                      = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist , timeout: timeout , js_errors: false )
capybara_session.driver.options[:js_errors]           = false
capybara_session.driver.options[:timeout]             = timeout
capybara_session.driver.options[:debug]               = true
capybara_session.driver.options[:phantomjs_logger]    = true
capybara_session.driver.options[:stdout]              = true
capybara_session.driver.options[:phantomjs_options]   = ['--proxy-type=none','--load-images=no','--ignore-ssl-errors=yes','--ssl-protocol=any','--web-security=false','--debug=true']
```

Do some actions with the session .........

```
capybara_session.try(:reset_session!)

capybara_session.try(:driver).try(:quit)
```